# Program that counts numbers in the way humans do

Tags: java, counting

In class we were given a project to make a program that counts numbers in a natural way the humans do and so if a user puts in 2 inputs, our program counts the numbers in between the way humans are supposed to count (add 1 to the last digit, if the last digit is 9, adding 1 turns it to 0 and adds 1 to the digit before that) and returns a string with the input, output, and all numbers in between.

He gave us some code in class and now going over it I'm not sure what the parameters of his method mean at all so I don't understand where he's going with this:

```
static String nextNum(String base, String n) {
    int i=n.length()-1;
    char digit = n.charAt(i);
    int pos = base.indexOf(digit);
    n=n.substring(0,i-1) + base.charAt(pos+1); //next symbol in the base

    return n;
}
```

What are the two String parameters supposed to be? He also had a `for` loop on the board:

```
for (int i = n.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    char digit = n.charAt(i);
    int pos=base.indexOf(digit);

    if(pos==base.length()-1) { //case2 - for switching 9 to 0
        n=n.substring(0,i-1) + base.charAt(0)+n.substring(i+1);
    } else { //case1
        n=n.substring(0,i-1)+base.charAt(pos+1)+n.substring(i+1);
    }
}
```

Again, I'm not sure what `base` and `n` are supposed to be so it's hard for me to see what he's doing. I'm not asking for anyone to write the project for me, I would just really appreciate someone clearing this up for me and giving me tips on how to use this code to get the program he wants.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question before in the last couple of days, I just can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 0):

Base is the character set for your numbers. For example, for base 10, the way people normally count, the string would be "0123456789". For base 2 (binary), the string would be "01".

The string n is the number that you need to increment. For example, say we use base 10 (String is "0123456789") and the number we want to increment is 19. In this case, the string n would be "19".

Now, let's see what happens in the loop.

```
for (int i = n.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
```

Here, we start with i = 2 - 1 = 1.
So

```
char digit = n.charAt(i);
int pos=base.indexof(digit);
```

digit will be '9' (the second character), and pos would be the position of that character in base, so 9.

The condition `if(pos==base.length()-1)` will be fulfilled, and '9' will be replaced with '0'.

In the second iteration, the condition would not be fulfilled, and the digit '1' will be incremented to '2', and the result would '20' as needed.

However, for the string n of value "11", the output will be "22". Fix the code.

Comment: Precisely. It seems like there is some error in the OP's code, for cases similar to the one you mentioned. I tried to look at it with a slightly different approach to make the OP understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: Hm, I tried to run the code to see if 19 would increment to 20, but instead I got a string index out of bounds error at the line `n=n.substring(0,i-1)+base.charAt(pos+1)+n.substring(i+1);` in the for loop. Also, if the for loop does the incrementing, then what is the point of the method?

Comment: The for loop is actually almost the complete method. You got the exception because you method doesn't check if the digit is the last one or not and just assumes there's a next digit

Comment: My answer was referring to the loop

Comment: What confuses me is that he didn't call the method in the for loop at all. Are they supposed to work together or are they exclusive to each other?

Comment: The for loop IS the method. It's an implementation (albeit a flawed one), but it's clearly meant to be a standalone implementation for the method.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

The following code block will show you how to add 2 numbers, that are presented as strings. This is intended to help you understand how to get the `nextNumber` [getting the next number is the same as adding 1]. I haven't considered the negative number case here. And since I worked with base 10, the all `/` and `%` are with 10's. Hopefully, this will help you understand. Let me know if you want some clarifications.

```
String top = "34521";
String bottom = "123";

int topPtr = top.length() - 1;
int bottomPtr = bottom.length() - 1;
int carry = 0, curSum = 0;
StringBuilder sum = new StringBuilder();
while (topPtr != -1 && bottomPtr != -1) {
    int topVal = top.charAt(topPtr) - '0';
    int bottomVal = bottom.charAt(bottomPtr) - '0';
    curSum = topVal + bottomVal + carry;
    carry = curSum / 10;
    sum.append(curSum % 10);
    topPtr--;
    bottomPtr--;
}
while (topPtr != -1) {
    int topVal = top.charAt(topPtr) - '0';
    curSum = topVal + carry;
    carry = curSum / 10;
    sum.append(curSum % 10);
    topPtr--;
}

while (bottomPtr != -1) {
    int bottomVal = bottom.charAt(bottomPtr) - '0';
    curSum = bottomVal + carry;
    carry = curSum / 10;
    sum.append(curSum % 10);
    bottomPtr--;
}
System.out.println(sum.reverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

`nextNum` seems to be nearly complete already, only the overflow case is not covered. Basically you'll "just" need to add an else branch for the case where you run out of digits in the current position.

`base` Would typically be `0123456789`.

```
/**
 * Compute the successor of the parameter n, which is required to be
 * a String of digits from from the parameter base, representing a
 * number.
 */
static String nextNum(String base, String n) {
  int i = n.length() - 1;         // Index of the last digit in n
  char digit = n.charAt(i);       // The last digit 
  int pos = base.indexOf(digit);  // Position of the last digit in base
  if (pos + 1 < base.length) {    // Is there a "next" digit available in base?
     // Replace the last digit accordingly  
     n = n.substring(0, i) + base.charAt(pos + 1);  
  } else if (i > 0) {
     // Regular overflow case: 
     //   Increase the preceding digit(s) and  
     //   reset the last digit to 0 
     n = nextNum(base, n.substring(0, i)) + base.charAt(0);
  } else {
     // We need to add a digit
     n = "" + base.charAt(1) + base.charAt(0);
  }
  return n;
}
```

Comment: I tried using this to see what would happen with some test numbers, inputting 20 returns 1 and inputting 19 gives an error at `char digit = n.charAt(i);` and `n = nextNum(base, n.substring(0, i - 1)) + base.charAt(0);` saying String index out of range: -1, would you happen to know why that error pops up?

Comment: @JzO Fixed: The substring indices were off by 1 (the "-1" part was wrong -- the end index is exclusive already)